# How to update my app without losing settings?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 app which every user can have different settings, and some other data.

How can I release a new update without loosing those data. I see that the old version will get deleted before installing the new version. How to survive user's data?

(I hope no one come here and say where is your code :) .. it is about updating)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user installs the update from the marketplace the data should remain there (next time you update an app notice how you don't need to re-enter log in details, for example). It seems you're doing a full rebuild and deploying your app which uninstalls and reinstalls the app. To simulate an update, simply deploy the app from Visual Studio without `rebuilding` and you'll see that your data should remain there.

To do a proper test of updating, I suggest you look at [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Comment: So the point is `Building` or `Rebuilding`. So when I want everything be deleted I do a Rebuild. great. If I did a wrong rebuild on the main project, isn't there anyway to undo it and the app will get reinstalled?

Comment: No, if you've uninstalled the app, it clears the isolated storage. AFAIK, there's no way to get that back so you just have to avoid doing a full rebuild if you want to keep the isolates storage data. As a hack, and is completely untested, but you could try setting the modified date of the XAP file to something earlier before deploying (if you accidentally did a rebuild). I'm not sure if that's what's checked but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my apps plenty of times, and I can tell you that the IsolatedStorageSettings do *not* get cleared after an update from the Windows Phone Store.

If you do a rebuild of your app and deploy that to a client device with the app already there, the IsolatedStorage will be cleared as keyboardP already mentioned. But, I don't believe that a rebuild on your solution and publishing the re-built XAP will clear the storage.

Comment: I didn't understand your second paragraph

Comment: @Shi Basically, a rebuild of your app will _not_ affect the IsolatedStorage for those who updated from the Windows Phone Store.